# Custom cells in table view not displaying content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

I am new to auto layouts and iOS in general therefore I wanted to create Facebook newsfeed page in order to have my hands on auto layouts. 
I am using table view with custom cells. Things done till now are:

Dropped a tableview in storyboard.

Created its outlet in respective controller class.

Created controller classes for custom cells.

Dropped necessary views in both cells and created there outlets in necessary controller classes.

Set the appropriate and identifiers in of each custom cell.

Now the problem which I am facing is that the both cells are displaying correctly in the interface builder but in device or simulator only the first cell displays. Images here because of my reputation. [interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGJs2.png)

[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sodWd.png)

I searched alot but didn't find any appropriate answer. Where am I wrong?
Did I miss anything? Apparently there are no auto layout issues.

For instance, I am pasting the code of my controller class too.

```
class HomeScreen: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            if (indexPath.row == 0){
                return 100
            } else {
                return 200
            }
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                guard let cell : StatusUpdateCustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusUpdateCell" , for: indexPath) as? StatusUpdateCustomTableViewCell  else {
                    fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
                }

                cell.profilePicImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "teenGirl")
                return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                guard let cell : PostCustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell1" , for: indexPath) as? PostCustomTableViewCell  else {
                    fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
                }
                cell.profilePicImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "teenBoy")
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "thirdCustomCell")
                //set the data here
                return cell
            }
        }

        @IBOutlet weak var headerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView3: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView4: UIImageView!

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView1Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView2Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView3Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView4Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewPosts: UITableView!

        var windowWidth = 0.0;
        var windowHeight = 0.0;

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableViewPosts.delegate = self
            tableViewPosts.dataSource = self

            // calling rotated function when device orientation changes.
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("rotated"), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            //print(self.view.frame.size)
            windowWidth = Double(self.view.frame.width);
            windowHeight = Double(self.view.frame.height);
        }

        func rotated(){
            if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation)){
                // hiding imageview and underlining textfields
                print("landscape")
                headerViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.07)
                imageView1Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.07)
                imageView2Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.07)
                imageView3Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.07)
                imageView4Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.07)
            }

            if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation)){
                headerViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.001)
                imageView1Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.001)
                imageView2Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.001)
                imageView3Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.001)
                imageView4Height.constant = CGFloat(windowHeight * 0.001)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `@available(iOS 2.0, *)` makes no sense. iOS1.0 had no AppStore, so your app cannot be run on a device running an iOS version lower than 2.0 and with [89% of devices running iOS10](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) and 98% running iOS9 or 10 do you really think a significant amount of your users would still be running around with an original iPhone that they would have never software updated?

Comment: This thing was auto generated by Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you  are returning 1 row so

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        @available(iOS 2.0, *)
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1// It's Wrong
        }
```

Comment: I think you just copied my answer

Answer (score 2):

I can see from your code that you have implemented the numberOfRowsInSection twice and in one of the instances you return 10 and the other one you only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

You might be working with Swift 3.
The method which returns 1 is applicable in Swift 3 but not the method witch returns 10. This method will be treated as a an instance method(local to your controller). So in reality your table will show only 1 row.